# How do you set up a contact on a Motorola Moto G7 Power to dial in with pauses to a conference call?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, phone-app

How do you set up a contact on a Motorola Moto G7 Power to dial in with pauses to a conference call?

I'm helping a colleague with her phone. We're all working remotely and we are dialing in for conference calls. To dial in, one enters 3 numbers (the phone number, the access code and #, then 1 to confirm. I have my phone (Pixel 4) set up with a contact so that this happens all with one press. It looks like this in the contacts entry:
5551234567, 987654#, 1

To do this, the Pixel 4 has a second screen on the dialer with more characters:

[image: Pixel 4 dialer]

The dialer on the Motorola looks like this:

[image]

I don't see a second screen access, a comma, a pause or anything to string the numbers together.

Comment: You can try conference calling apps (many on Play Store). [This one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.itsystemsyd.conferencecaller) is recently updated, has a good rating. Only con is it has 4 trackers. You can  try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most standard dialers you have to type in at least one number or other character before left to the number-to-be-dialed a 3 dots menu appears that has an entry to `Add 2-sec pause`.

By selecting `Add 2-sec pause` a comma (`,`) is appended to the number-to-be-dialed.

[image]